# Бейдж разработчика дискорд бота

Tags: discord

Как в 2024 получить значок активного разработчика дискорд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте справочные материалы [Discord](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/ru/articles/10113997751447-%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Время от времени Discord проверяет, действительно ли вы занимаетесь разработкой, используя Discord API. Поэтому если вы хотите получить только значок разработчика, то знайте, Discord регулярно делает проверки.

Доказательство (источник: Discord Support):

> Право на получение значка активного разработчика, как указано выше в разделе "Я могу получить значок?", необходимо поддерживать, чтобы сохранить значок. Если бот не будет активен, значок будет потерян. После 30 дней бездействия вы рискуете потерять право на ношение значка. Мы отправим вам электронное письмо, и у вас будет еще 30 дней, чтобы исправить любые проблемы, прежде чем значок удалится из вашего профиля, так что следите за входящими письмами!

О получении:

1. Зайдите на [Портал Разработчика](https://discord.com/developers/active-developer)
2. Выберите активное приложение
3. Укажите сервер сообщества
4. Выберите новостной канал разработчика

После этих действий вы можете претендовать на значок разработчика, но **прежде** обязательно ознакомьтесь с руководством от поддержки Discord, который было приложено выше.

Comment: Не GPT ли случайно?

Comment: Нет конечно, мне несложно расписать самому.

Comment: Извиняюсь тогда. Стиль просто очень похож.

Comment: Согласен с Глебом, похож на Chat-GPT